# Hybrid Application Automation - unable to find xpath in webview mode

Tags: android, selenium, webview, appium, inspector

I'm working on Hybrid Application Automation.

I have asked a developer to provide webview enabled `.apk` file for automation.
 I got the `.apk` and I installed in on my real device (Samsung Galaxy) and checked in c`hrome://inspect` to view the app in inspector mode. - It is displayed

In my code I have tried `System.out.println("ContextName:- " + contextNames);` to check that Native and Webview context displaying. It successfully displayed both Webview and Native.

I have the following issue:
 I'm able to find element till my `Login` page (using Native and Webview context).

After `Login` page I have a main screen in mobile app that contains list of tables and text, links, thus I'm unable to find any element in this page.

I tried copying the xpath using => `inspector` - `copyxpath` feature. I searched with that xpath in Chrome inspector and it's highlighted (showing) the elements. I'm using the same xpath in my code to check the size of that xpath details. But it's showing `size = 0` for all my elements.

I also tried:

- I swicthed to Webview context once after the login page;
- I switched to Webview mode before login screen itself.

Still, I'm unable to find any element on my page.

Is it possible to capture all available elements in the page to check if at least I'm on right track? I'm not sure where is the mistake I made. Can any one suggest me some solution?

***!!! Note:*** I have the following limitation: I can only use a real (physical) device, not an emulator.

**Code:**

```
    File f = new File("D:\\APK\\");     
    File fs = new File(f,"android-4.0-8071-Pulse_Deb_Mode.apk");

    AndroidDriver driver;           
    DesiredCapabilities cap =new DesiredCapabilities();
    //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Auto1");      
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"89959777"); //5bce9757      

    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());      
    //cap.setCapability("appPackage", "au.com.ventia.apps.WMS");
    //cap.setCapability("appActivity", "au.com.ventia.apps.WMS.MainActivity");
    //cap.setCapability("platformName", "MobilePlatform.ANDROID");
    //cap.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
    //cap.setCapability("autoWebview", true);
    //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "BROWSER");
      //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.4.2"); 
      //cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "21");

    driver = new AndroidDriver (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);       
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);     

    System.out.println(((AndroidDriver) driver).getOrientation());      
    System.out.println("Device Connected");     
    try{

        Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
         for (String contextName : contextNames) {
            System.out.println("ContextName:- "+contextNames); //prints out something like NATIVE_APP \n WEBVIEW_1
            // System.out.println("Working as:-  "+  driver.getTitle());         
        }

        Thread.sleep(40000);
        driver.context((String) contextNames.toArray()[1]); // set context to WEBVIEW_1

        List<WebElement> user_name = driver.findElementsById("userNameInput");          
        List<WebElement> pass_name = driver.findElementsById("passwordInput");  
        System.out.println("Checking"+user_name.size() + pass_name.size());

        user_name.get(0).clear();
        pass_name.get(0).clear();
        user_name.get(0).sendKeys("<<>><<>>");
        pass_name.get(0).sendKeys("<<>><<><");
        driver.pressKeyCode(66);

        Thread.sleep(30000);
        //driver.context((String) contextNames.toArray()[0]); // set context to WEBVIEW_1

        List<WebElement> li = driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@id='app']/ion-pane/ion-side-menus/ion-side-menu-content/ion-header-bar/div[3]");
        System.out.println("Check1-"+li.size());

        List<WebElement> li2 = driver.findElementsByXPath(".//*[@id='app']/ion-pane/ion-side-menus/ion-side-menu-content/ion-header-bar/div[3]");
        System.out.println("Refresh-"+li2.size());

        List<WebElement> li3 = driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/ion-pane/ion-side-menus/ion-side-menu-content/ion-header-bar/div[3]");
        System.out.println("Satus"+li3.size());

        List<WebElement> li4 = driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@id=\"au.com.ventia.apps.WMS\"]/ion-pane/ion-side-menus/ion-side-menu-content/ion-header-bar/div[3]");
        System.out.println("Task"+li4.size());

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error Code---> "+e);
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
PORTRAIT
Device Connected
ContextName:- [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_au.com.ventia.apps.WMS]
ContextName:- [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_au.com.ventia.apps.WMS]
Checking11
Check1-0
Refresh-0
Satus0
Task0
```

Comment: If you have a mach machine , you can easily view all the xpath by recording the operation.

Comment: Thanks for the help - It's showing a different error now. unknown error: Chrome version must be >= 53.0.2785.0 , Can you please help me on this. I'm using emulator now. Installed android Webview app. Now i'm able to see only Native_app ( Webview is missing). Tried so many ways.

Comment: can you share the screen UI using UI automator to me, so that i can help you